# python check if the folder content existed

Tags: python, csv

The purpose of this code is:

Read a csv file which contains a column for a list of file names

here is the csv file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5bJvxM9TZkhVGI5dkdLVzAyNTA

Then check a specific folder to check if the files exist or not

If its found a file is not in the list delete it

here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os.path

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
names = data['title']
path = "C:\\Users\\Sayed\\Desktop\\Economic Data"

for file in os.listdir(path):
    os.path.exists(file)
    print(file)
    file = os.path.join(path, file)
    fileName = os.path.splitext(file)

    if fileName not in names:
        print('error')
        os.remove(file)
```

I modified the first code, and this is the new code and I got no error but the simply delete all the files in the directory

Comment: _Please_ read the documentation for `os.chdir` (and notice its lack of return value)...

Comment: `os.chdir` does not return a value. Thus, path is a `NoneType`

Answer (score 2):

`os.chdir` does not return anything, so assigning the result to `path` means that `path` has `None`, which causes the error.

Since you're using pandas, here's a little trick to speed this up using `pd.Series.isin`.

```
root = "C:\Users\Sayed\Desktop\Economic Data"
files = os.listdir(root)

for f in data.loc[~data['title'].isin(files), 'title'].tolist():
    try:
        os.remove(os.path.join(root, f))
    except OSError:
        pass
```

Added a `try-except` check in accordance with EAFP (since I'm not doing an `os.path.exists` check here). Alternatively, you could add a filter based on existence using `pd.Series.apply`:

```
m = ~data['title'].isin(files) & data['title'].apply(os.path.exists)

for f in data.loc[m, 'title'].tolist():
    os.remove(os.path.join(root, f))
```

Comment: the folder contain the original files and some outsider files and no outsider file deleted

Comment: @sayedgouda Please check `f`, does it have any spaces in it?

Comment: it does not have any

Comment: @sayedgouda I'm not sure what you want me to do. I believe this code is correct.

Comment: Remove the try-except and see if any errors are thrown.

Comment: @sayedgouda If it's useless, all the best - now start debugging. I don't have access to your computer, so please don't expect me to solve your problems. Like I said, this code is fine. I'll say one more thing - you're not supposed to add anything to my code except the code to create `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `path` is the *return value* of the os.chdir() call. Which is obviously `None`.
You want to set `path` to the string representing the path ... leave the chdir out.